# Using the `br` tag in an HTML webpage

Tags: html

Here is a summary from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp for the `<br>` tag:

- The `<br>` tag inserts a single line break.
- The `<br>` tag is an empty tag which means that it has no end tag.
- In HTML, the `<br>` tag has no end tag.
- In XHTML, the `<br>` tag must be properly closed, like this: `<br />`.

So can I safely use `<br>` in a webpage (or any other HTML snippet) without closing it?

And if I'm advised to close it, then is this the correct way: `<br><br/>` (with nothing in between)?

Comment: Yes, provided you're not using an XHTML doctype. Just use `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: why not just using the <br />? It's always valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `<br>` is a *void tag* (meaning it cannot wrap any content inside), you can either use it as `<br>` or `<br/>` (the trailing `/` will be ignored), but `<br></br>` is *invalid*.

If you want your markup to be valid XML, then use `<br/>`, but that is irrelevant for a HTML parser.

This, according to the (latest) [HTML5 specs, section elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if you use `<br>` or `<br/>` in the newer versions of HTML, but it is recommended to close all the HTML tags, using `<br/>` (and not `<br></br>`). The same is tru for `<hr/>`, `<img src="..." />` etc.

Answer (score 0):

For older HTML yes, for modern, like 4 or 5 is has become a standard to close all tags.  There may come a day when they will just not work anymore.  Other words, todays HTML is strict like XHTML.

Comment: You don't need to close elements that don't have content models, provided you have a doctype like `<!DOCTYPE html>`. This *will not break in the future*. Today's HTML is not like XHTML. XHTML is very strict about its expectations - it doesn't permit unknown tags, elements, etc. It requires all elements to be closed, or self-closed.

Comment: @JonathanSampson - Are you sure that you want to make the statement this will not break in the future?

Comment: Yes, Sir. If you are following standards, this will not break in the future. `<br>` is a standard, and as long as you are using a Standards doctype, you will have no issues.

Comment: @JonathanSampson, Hmmm,  then maybe you can help me with that LISTING tag, since it was part of the standard in HTML 3.02, but I just cannot seems to get it to work today.  I am sure back in 1994 someone thought wow LISTING will always be there in the future. :)

Comment: Unlike `<br>`, the `<listing>` element wasn't implemented by all browsers. Those that did implement it didn't exactly have a consistent implementation either. That being said, it is trivial to get the the `<pre>` effect with `<listing>` today if you need it for legacy support. I'd be happy to assist :)

Comment: @JonathanSampson the point that I am trying to make is that Listing was part of the standard.  and <BR /> is the preferred method and not <BR>  and that <BR> could be removed in the future.  Never say Never in IT.  for instance 10 years ago a lot of people said javascript was good for the web or appliances, but would never be used anywhere else, and they did not need to learn it.  Now we use it on mobile devices as well as it is used for server and general machine setup.

Comment: Some things can get removed (such as `<hgroup>`), but `<br>` will never be one of them. There doesn't exist a persuasive enough argument, and too much of the web would be forever broken if browsers started changing the functionality of the break tag. Respectfully, it simply won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe and works but it is not something generally recommended.

HTML5 doesn't care if you close it or not, it should work everywhere well, but I always prefer to use the valid structure that conforms to XML standards.